# merge from one dataframe values with one dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have one difficulty here. My goal is to create a list of sales for one shop with one dataframe that lists prices by product and one other that lists all the sales in terms of products and quantities (for one period of time)

DataFrame 1 : prices

```
prices = pd.DataFrame({'qty_from' : ('0','10','20'), 'qty_to' : ('9','19','29'), 'product_A' :(50,30,10),'product_B' :(24,14,12),'product_C' :(70,50,18)})
```

DataFrame 2 : sales

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({'product' : ('product_b','product_b','product_a',product_c,product_b), 'qty' : ('4','12','21','41','7')})
```

I would like to get the turnover, line by line within the 'sales' DataFrame, with one other column like 'TurnOver'

I used

```
pd.merge_asof(sales, prices, left_on='qty', right_on='qty_from', direction='backward')
```

and it gave me the right price for the quantity sold, but how to get the good price that is related to one product? 
How to merge with a value in 'sales' dataframe like 'product_b' with the name of a column in dataframe prices, here 'product_b' and then apply a calculation to get the turnover ?

Thank you for your help,

Eric

Comment: could you display a sample what you have and what you want, it will be easier to understant

Comment: Frenchy . Thank you for you interest. Ben T found the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can modify the dataframe prices to be able to use the parameter `by` in `merge_asof`, using `stack`:

```
#modify price
prices_stack = (prices.set_index(['qty_from','qty_to']).stack() # then products become as a column
                     .reset_index(name='price').rename(columns={'level_2':'product'}))

# uniform the case
sales['product'] = sales['product'].str.lower()
prices_stack['product'] = prices_stack['product'].str.lower()
# this is necessary with your data here as not int
sales.qty = sales.qty.astype(int)
prices_stack.qty_from = prices_stack.qty_from.astype(int)

#now you can merge_asof adding by parameter
sales_prices = (pd.merge_asof( sales.sort_values('qty'), prices_stack, 
                               left_on='qty', right_on='qty_from', 
                               by = 'product', #first merge on the column product
                               direction='backward')
                  .drop(['qty_from','qty_to'], axis=1)) #not necessary columns

print (sales_prices)
     product  qty  price
0  product_b    4     24
1  product_b    7     24
2  product_b   12     14
3  product_a   21     10
4  product_c   41     18
```

Comment: Ben T thank you for your reply, this is exactly what I was expecting for. Stack function is 'magic' here and give me the chance to turn out columns names into index and then in values for each prices. Thank you for your promprt reply. I really appreciate it. Eric

Comment: @boskey50 glad it helped and you learn something from it, it's what this community is about :)